# How to return acknowledgment to the caller before start long execution in Java

Tags: java, web-services

I have a service method exposed to external clients like this:

```
public String service()
 {
    String track_id;

    // Generate new track id for each call somehow
    // let us put as 123 for simplicity
    track_id = "123";

    // Execution that may take 1 minute goes here ....

    return track_id;
  }
```

Then I have a client that consumes the service like:

```
public void client()
 {
    // Method Call
    String track_id = service();

    // Other statements
    //statement 1;
    //statement 2;
    //statement 3;
  }
```

The only thing that `client()` is caring about is the track id returned by `service()`. `client()` is not caring about the long execution process taking place in `service()` that delays the statements 1 to 3 in `client()`.

Now is there any way to let `service()` return the track id first then run the rest of execution. Sound crazy, but is there any way to change `service()` method in a way to achieve the following behavior:

```
public String service()
 {
    String track_id;

    // Generate new track id for each call somehow
    // let us put as 123 for simplicity
    track_id = "123";

    return track_id;

    // Execution that may take 1 minute goes here ....
  }
```

Note: I do not want to store anything in DB then fetch it later in any way in order to run the long execution in `service()`. Long execution should run at the time of receiving a call from `client()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to be executed in a thread of a pool managed by the container. The response will not be sent to client until your method finish

You can run the long task starting a separate thread and let the main thread end up returning the track id

```
public String service() {
    String track_id;

    // Generate new track id for each call somehow
    // let us put as 123 for simplicity
    track_id = "123";

    //Asynchronous thread
    (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          // Execution that may take 1 minute goes here ....
       }
    }).start();

   return track_id;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to use two methods?

```
public String fastService() {
    String track_id;
    track_id = "123";
    return track_id;
}
```

You want probably to work with the generated id.

```
public String slowService(String id) {
    // zzZzZZzZZ     
}
```

And in the client call in the order you need:

```
public void client() {
    String track_id = fastService();
    // Other statements
    slowService(track_id);
}
```

---

**But, be cautious!** If you call the methods in this order, will it affect the behavior? What if the slow service does not succeed, will you generate the id again?